# Can't chown mounted HDD under sudo

Tags: chown

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 in another attempt to drop away from Windows, and am having an issue with my two HDDs.

I've gone through the entirety of this tutorial very carefully, but I think either it, or I, am missing something.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

Whenever I try to either chown the HDD mounts to me, or create a folder, I get a permission error. I've tried to chown it via 'sudo nautilus' and 'sudo chown -R bozotheclown: /media' to no effect. Here's my terminal log.

```
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$ sudo chown -R bozotheclown: /media
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD2’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1/.Trash-0/info/gfvn.trashinfo’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1/.Trash-0/info’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1/.Trash-0/files/gfvn’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1/.Trash-0/files’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1/.Trash-0’: Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of ‘/media/HDD1’: Operation not permitted
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$ mkdir /media/HDD1/sf
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/HDD1/sf’: Permission denied
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$ sudo !!
sudo mkdir /media/HDD1/sf
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$ ls /media/HDD1
sf
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$ sudo nautilus
bozotheclown@bozotheclown-MS-7759:~$
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Show us your mounts.

```
cat /etc/fstab
mount
```

There's very little to go on here, but I will hazard a guess that you're trying to change permissions on a file system like vfat that simply doesn't have anything like *nix ownership and permissions.

For such filesystems, you should focus on the "uid=NNNN,gid=NNNN" options in the fstab that define what the mount will "pretend" are the owner and group for the contents.

Comment: /dev/sda1    /media/HDD1   vfat    defaults     0        2
/dev/sdc1    /media/HDD2   vfat    defaults     0        2

Comment: I assume I need to change that to something like

    /dev/sda1 /media/HDD1 vfat defaults 1000 2

?

Comment: You probably want the lines to read like "/dev/sda1 /media/HDD1 vfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0 2"  ... assuming your user id and group ID are "1000". Use the "id" command to check.

Comment: Got the uid. Got it working actually, but I'll add in gid and umask. Thanks!